# I've found some tags in a text/template javascript script and I'm not sure what they are

Tags: javascript, php, templates

I've come across the following script.

```
<script type="text/template" id="recent-search-template">
    ...
   <%= data.city_from_id.title %> (<%= data.city_from %>)
    ...
</script>
```

My question is simple. What are these tags `<%=` and `%>`. I've never seen them before and google isn't much help as I'm not sure what to search for.

The closest thing I can think of is the PHP short tag equivalent for javascript(the also seem quite similar, PHP uses `<?=` and `?>`), but I'm not sure and I'd like to find out.

The script is located in a `*.php` file, if it makes any difference.

After some digging around they seem very similar to [`asp_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). But, again I'm not entirely sure that's the case here.

Comment: They are part of some client-side templating system, eg. handlebars, john resigs microtemplates, etc.

Comment: @Shilly Oh. Well, I dunno what I was expecting. If it makes any difference, I've updated my question with some new info.

Comment: The  `text/template` indicates that it is a template. And searching for `javascript template "<%="`  in e.g. Google will lead you to [EJS - JavaScript Templates](http://www.embeddedjs.com/) on the first result page. So It might be that it is a EJS template or a template using the same syntax.

Comment: I didn't know which template system, so thanks Vlad. :) Basically by giving the script tag an invalid type (text/template) it won't throw an error since it wo'nt be run as a script, it';s just inert text that doesn't get used. But you can still select that script tag, so once you have to render the template this represents, EJS will select that script tag, parse it and replace the text with the correct value. (the title property of the city object in this case) It's a nice way to geenrate dynamic HTML without having to manually build HTML tags with string concats or node manipulation.

Comment: Using the Find feature in your editor to search your project for mentions of `recent-search-template` would probably use a sensible way to find where this was used.

Comment: The thing is, the project doesn't use [EJS - JavaScript Templates](http://www.embeddedjs.com/). At least as far as I can tell. I've looked thru the page in question and it doesn't load anything related to EJS.

Comment: Then they must be asp tags. You can check this using php echo and see if the string appears on the page and make sure the setting for those tags is turned on, more info here: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag.
Otherwise something is missing from you project because as t.niese said the fact that the <script> tag has the type="text/template" it implies that the code uses some kind of client side library.

Answer (score 1):

These are ASP short tags that were supported in PHP as well until PHP version 7.

`<%=` tag serves same purpose as PHP echo short tag `<?=`

See more on following link.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Answer (score 0):

That looks like [EJS](http://www.embeddedjs.com/)
It's a client side template, but it can also be used with Server Side data using Node.js, but since it's in a PHP file it could load only client side data.

I encourage you to search the other files to find out what your project is using because in open source all the code is available for you to read.

Comment: The project is written in PHP almost entirely, but it's somewhat old. About 4-5 years, I assume. There are about 3 or 4 files that have this sort of script and tags. Thing is they work properly, i mean there's noting funky going on or anything.

Comment: @Andrew — PHP won't be processing template code that is delivered to the client in a script element. PHP runs server side.

Comment: Yes, I'm well aware of that. I was just pointing out the fact that it's written in PHP, nothing more.